# Excel application.ontime in other application than Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently working with Attachmate Reflection emulator, which supports VBA.

I've added Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library to References, and I've tried to run excel.application.ontime event, but it does not work, and returns error:
"Cannot run the macro 'paymentList'.

The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled."

This is example of a code,
(btw the code is correct, it works in Excel well):

```
Sub addPaymentListReminders()
    Excel.Application.OnTime TimeSerial(9, 22, 0), "paymentList", TimeSerial(9, 23, 0)
End Sub



Sub paymentList()
    MsgBox "Payment list time!", vbExclamation
End Sub
```

I've already checked, and Attachmate Reflection does not support ontime event,
any idea if this problem can be solved?

Comment: Maybe you should ask Attachmate about their product if you wish to use it. But if they (themselves) say that they don't support it then the case seems pretty clear.

Comment: Is your `paymentList` routine actually in the Excel document you're automating? It's hard to tell from your code, but if what you've posted above is entirely within Reflection then this is not going to work because the `OnTime` function will only execute code within the Excel document you have open.

Comment: Yes, it's within Reflection, so It's not gonna work.
Thanks for your answers!